# Double summation in R without loops

Tags: r

I have following double summation:
∑10,i=1 ∑i,j=1 (i^5/(10+j^i))

(as seen on this picture [Double summation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHKKU.png)

I am quite lost with this exercise, I tried the following code but I am not sure this is a correct way to find the solution

```
  i <- seq(1, 10, 1) 
  j <- seq(1, i, 1)
  denominators <- 10+j^i
  fractions <- (i^5)/denominators
  sum(fractions)
```

or

```
  i = rep(1:10, each=5)
  j = rep(i, 10)
  # find the sum 
  sum(i^5/(10+j^i))
```

Comment: Oups, I think that is a mistake - I tried to do the same as I did where i = 5

Comment: If this is for a course, it would be helpful to know what functions you have been covering. I don't see a purely vectorized solution, but we could, e.g., generate all the `i,j` combinations by hiding loops (e.g., with `sapply` or `expand.grid` and a subset) and then calculate the sum in a vectorized way.

Comment: Thank you, I understand - it is for a beginners course in R, so we mainly covered the basic functions up till loops and cycles, and have used sapply as well.  I am just not sure how to implement it in this case and I was also not sure if sapply qualifies as a loop or not? Thank you again for your answer!

Comment: You can do this in a fully vectorized (but wasteful) way: You need `outer`, `lower.tri` and `sum`.

Comment: Could you please explain me how this would work, I did not work with some of these functions before?